# Excel file which have macro enable not opening in IE

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel

I've a requirement in which an excel file( Macro Enabled) is stored in SharePoint 2010 and when user clicks the file, it should open in the IE as read only file.

The Excel file is opening in the IE with out any issue, but the macro buttons is not showing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

excel macro buttons (done via the macro interface) don't show up in the browser version of excel, the macro buttons would have to be activex buttons instead (not sure if they work that way though, I haven't tried).